# Retrieving a value from the request in twig - Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm sure that I have managed to do this before but for some reason it's not working correctly.

I have a page in my project that lists clients by their account status. It's not mandatory, but a status CAN be passed via the URL, else it simply lists the active clients.

example:

> myurl.com/clients/closed

would list all the clients with closed accounts.

My route is set up as follows:

```
app_show_clients:
    path: /clients/{status}
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Client:showClients, status: 'active' }
    requirements:
        status: active|closed
```

And in my Twig file, I am attempting to retrieve the status as follows:

```
{{ app.request.get('status') }}
```

in order to show the status in the title of the page.

However, this just comes back as blank - though if I write:

```
{{ dump(app.request.get('status')) }}
```

It gives me the value "closed" in the var dump.

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance
Michael

Comment: OK - I was actually being stupid...it was working, I'd just put the code in the wrong place so was not paying attention ._.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be better to use the controller to handle the request properly?

```
function showClientsAction($status)
{
    // Do some important stuff to fetch clients matching the request

    // Return array assumes @Template annotation usage
    return array('clients' => $clients, 'status' => $status);
}
```

So you could simply write `{{ status }}` in your template.

Comment: Yes, that's a viable alternative. Though, I've realised it was my own fault and it was actually working after all, as per my comment above.

Comment: Nice to hear, that you've worked it out. The webprofiler is always a good starting point to check if everything is ok. You should update the question with your "answer" to mark it closed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try by this way:

`{{ app.request.query.get("status") }}`

Answer (score 0):

Issue has been solved - I had placed the code in the wrong place, therefore I thought it had failed when it actually was working using:

```
{{ app.request.get('status') }}
```

which is the correct way.